# ffmpeg api alternate transcoding and remuxing for same file

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, c++14

### Context

Hello !

I'm currently working on the development of a small library allowing to cut an h.264 video on any frame, but without re-encoding (transcoding) the whole video. The idea is to re-encode only the GOP on which we want to cut, and to rewrite (remux) directly the others GOP.

The avcut project (https://github.com/anyc/avcut) allows to do that, but requires a systematic decoding of each package, and seems to not work with the recent versions of ffmpeg from the tests I could do and from the recent feedbacks in the github issues.

As a beginner, I started from the code examples provided in the ffmpeg documentation, in particular: [transcoding.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html) and [remuxing.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/remuxing_8c-example.html).

### Problem encountered

The problem I'm having is that I can't get both transcoding and remuxing to work properly at the same time. In particular, depending on the method I use to initialize the [AVCodecParameters](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecParameters.html) of the output video stream, transcoding works, or remuxing works:

- `avcodec_parameters_copy` works well for remuxing
- `avcodec_parameters_from_context` works well for transcoding

In case I choose `avcodec_parameters_from_context`, the transcoded GOP are correctly read by my video player (*parole*), but the remuxed packets are not read, and ffprobe does not show/detect them.

In case I choose `avcodec_parameters_from_context`, the remuxing GOP are correctly read by my video player, but the transcoding key_frame are bugged (I have the impression that the b-frame and p-frame are ok), and `ffprobe -i` return an error about the NAL of the key-frames:

```bash
[h264 @ 0x55ec8a079300] sps_id 32 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55ec8a079300] Invalid NAL unit size (1677727148 > 735).
[h264 @ 0x55ec8a079300] missing picture in access unit with size 744
```

I suspect that the problem is related to the extradata of the packets. Through some experiments on the different attributes of the output [AVCodecParameters](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecParameters.html), it seems that it is the `extradata` and `extradata_size` attributes that are responsible for the functioning of one method or the other.

### Version

ffmpeg development branch retrieved on 2022-05-17 from https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.

Compiled with `--enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-decoder=png --enable-encoder=png`

### Code

My code is written in c++ and is based on two classes: a class defining the parameters and methods on the input file (`InputContexts`) and a class defining them for the output file (`OutputContexts`). The code of these two classes is defined in the following files:

- [contexts.h](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vW_vGGGJ_tpLMFtcI_aw_xNReCwAeDe_/view?usp=sharing)
- [contexts.cpp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q7MYcXkSnUcdWasvAGT7TIY0gIOim2Df/view?usp=sharing)

The code normally involved in the problem is the following:

- stream initialization

```cpp
int OutputContexts::init(const char* out_filename, InputContexts* input_contexts){
    int ret;
    int stream_index = 0;

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, out_filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create output context\n");
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        return ret;
    }

    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, out_filename, 1);
 
    encoders.resize(input_contexts->ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, nullptr);
    codecs.resize(input_contexts->ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, nullptr);
  
    // stream mapping
    for (int i = 0; i < input_contexts->ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *out_stream;
        AVStream *in_stream = input_contexts->ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVCodecContext* decoder_ctx = input_contexts->decoders[i];
 
        // add new stream to output context
        out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!out_stream) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            return ret;
        }

        // from avcut blog
        av_dict_copy(&out_stream->metadata, in_stream->metadata, 0);

        out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;

        // encoder
        if (decoder_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO){
            ret = prepare_encoder_video(i, input_contexts);
            if (ret < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error while preparing encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }

            // from avcut
            out_stream->sample_aspect_ratio = in_stream->sample_aspect_ratio;

            // works well for remuxing
            ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_stream->codecpar);
            if (ret < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy codec parameters\n");
                return ret;
            }

            // works well for transcoding
            // ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, encoders[i]);
            // if (ret < 0) {
            //     av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream #%u\n", i);
            //     return ret;
            // }

        } else if (decoder_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }

        // TODO useful ???
        // set current stream position to 0
        // out_stream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
    }

    // opening output file in write mode with the ouput context
    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", out_filename);
            return ret;
        }
    }
 
    // write headers from output context in output file
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

- AVCodecContext initialization for encoder

```cpp
int OutputContexts::prepare_encoder_video(int stream_index, InputContexts* input_contexts){
    int ret;
    const AVCodec* encoder;
    AVCodecContext* decoder_ctx = input_contexts->decoders[stream_index];
    AVCodecContext* encoder_ctx;

    if (video_index >= 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Impossible to mark stream #%u as video, stream #%u is already registered as video stream.\n", 
                stream_index, video_index);
        return -1; //TODO change this value for correct error code
    }
    video_index = stream_index;

    if(decoder_ctx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264){
        encoder = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264");
        if (!encoder) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Encoder libx264 not found\n");
            return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
        }
        fmt::print("Encoder libx264 will be used for stream {}.\n", stream_index);
    } else {
        std::string s = fmt::format("No video encoder found for the given codec_id: {}\n", avcodec_get_name(decoder_ctx->codec_id));
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, s.c_str());
        return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
    }
    
    encoder_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
    if (!encoder_ctx) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    // from avcut
    encoder_ctx->time_base = decoder_ctx->time_base;
    encoder_ctx->ticks_per_frame = decoder_ctx->ticks_per_frame;
    encoder_ctx->delay = decoder_ctx->delay;
    encoder_ctx->width = decoder_ctx->width;
    encoder_ctx->height = decoder_ctx->height;
    encoder_ctx->pix_fmt = decoder_ctx->pix_fmt;
    encoder_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = decoder_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;
    encoder_ctx->color_primaries = decoder_ctx->color_primaries;
    encoder_ctx->color_trc = decoder_ctx->color_trc;
    encoder_ctx->colorspace = decoder_ctx->colorspace;
    encoder_ctx->color_range = decoder_ctx->color_range;
    encoder_ctx->chroma_sample_location = decoder_ctx->chroma_sample_location;
    encoder_ctx->profile = decoder_ctx->profile;
    encoder_ctx->level = decoder_ctx->level;

    encoder_ctx->thread_count = 1; // spawning more threads causes avcodec_close to free threads multiple times
    encoder_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
    
    // correct values ???
    encoder_ctx->qmin = 16;
    encoder_ctx->qmax = 26;
    encoder_ctx->max_qdiff = 4;
    // end from avcut

    // according to avcut, should not be set
    // if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER){
    //     encoder_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    // }

    ret = avcodec_open2(encoder_ctx, encoder, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", stream_index);
        return ret;
    }
    
    codecs[stream_index] = encoder;
    encoders[stream_index] = encoder_ctx;

    return ret;
}
```

### Example

To illustrate my problem, I provide here a test code using the two classes that alternates between transcoding and remuxing at each key-frame encountered in the file using my classes.

- [trans_remux.cpp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16t9LTWdWkCVXiFBlC7Dm2dIgk3EgQXDN/view?usp=sharing)

To compile the code:

```bash
g++ -o trans_remux trans_remux.cpp contexts.cpp -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS `pkg-config --libs libavfilter` -lfmt -g
```

Currently the code is using `avcodec_parameters_copy` (`contexts.cpp:333`), so it works well for remuxing. If you want to test the version with `avcodec_parameters_from_context`, pls comment from line 333 to 337 in `contexts.cpp` and uncomment from line 340 to 344 and recompile.